# Selecting a record with the max time stamp from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 2 tables:

**Participants**

deviceid, name

**DeviceLocation**

deviceid, gpslocation, timestamp

The DeviceLocation table is populated every few minutes with the latest GPS location of the device.

How can I get a list of all devices and the corresponding gps location and participant name with the **latest** timestamp?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I am attempting a join, but not getting anywhere

Comment: Join (Select max(timestamp) as t, deviceid from DeviceLocation group by deviceid) as t on t.deviceid...   might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT deviceid,timestamp,gpslocation,name 
FROM Participants p1
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM DeviceLocation d2 WHERE p1.deviceid = d2.deviceid)
GROUP BY deviceid;
```

Comment: Thanks, why is the group by clause needed at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.gpslocation, B.timestamp
FROM Participants A JOIN DeviceLocation B
ON A.deviceid=B.deviceid JOIN
(SELECT MAX(`timestamp`) max_timestamp 
 FROM DeviceLocation) C 
ON B.`timestamp`=C.max_timestamp;
```

I think you could instead fetch the data base on time intervals since the rate at which the data are inserted might be high. You could try something like:

```
SELECT A.*, B.gpslocation, B.timestamp
FROM Participants A JOIN DeviceLocation B
ON A.deviceid=B.deviceid 
WHERE B.`timestamp`>=NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this